# Is asking why a certain piece of music sounds "strange" on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have read the help section, but just to be sure, I would like to know if a question like the following would be on topic.

There is a song that at a specific point (it goes from a part with lyrics to a guitar solo) it feels "dissonant" (for a lack of a better word in my vocabulary). May I ask why it gives this impression? (I will link to the official video and give the specific time mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you are actually saying two things here, one of which seems off topic and one which I think could fit the site scope:

- "strange" is very opinion-based so would likely be closed rapidly
- asking what causes a dissonance seems to fit more with music theory

So my guidance would be to post it, but to write it to focus on theory rather than opinion.

Comment: I posted my question an I tried to be as factual as possible. Thank you for the input.